# getitembyid and update list immediately

Tags: list, sharepoint-server

I have below code which updates list

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

    oListItem = oList.getItemById(id);



    oListItem.set_item('Age', 45);

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () { success(id); }), Function.createDelegate(this, this.Fail));
```

This works fine.

What i need is to have few other fields from list when i use `getitembyId`
How can i get those fields from list and then update list.

Comment: You get all fields when you use getItemaById you can update them as you have done for Age

Answer (score 1):

To get an item value, modify it, then update the item your call will have to change a bit because you will need to `load` the item, `executeQueryAsync` to retrieve the item info, use the item info to make a change, call `update`, then run `executeQueryAsync` again...

```
(function () {
    var id = 1;
    var listName = "YourListName";
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
    var oListItem = oList.getItemById(id);
    // need to load the listItem to retrieve values from it
    ctx.load(oListItem);
    // executeQueryAsync to fetch the data we requested with load
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        // get the value we want and then modify it
        var ageVar = oListItem.get_item("Age");
        ageVar += 1;
        // set the item value and call update
        oListItem.set_item("Age", ageVar);
        oListItem.update();
        // call executeQueryAsync one last time to execute the update
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            success(id);
        }, function (sender, args) {
            // failed updating item
        });
    },
    function (sender, args) {
        // failed retrieving item
    });
} ());
```

Comment: I dont want to set many fields. Logic is i pass id and then it should return other columns. For example pass id and get value of Age field.then i will add 1 year to value of Age returned. Then set that Field age with value i modified.

Comment: @Happy The answer to your question is substantially different now that I understand what you're trying to do, the edit above should reflect your situation